# Hyper-V production checkpoints not being deleted after Veeam replication job on same Windows guest OS

Tags: backup, hyper-v, veeam

I am running two physical Windows 2016 servers in a clustered environment. The backup solution is Veeam Backup and Replication V11.

I have a replication job that has been failing regularly because the host server isn't merging the production checkpoints after.

I have to manually shut the guest down, wait for the checkpoints to merge, then power it back on. THe replication job then runs successfully but within 1-2 days the same issue occurs and I have to go through the same process again.

The guest OS is Server 2019 core.

The Hyper-V Worker event logs for the FAILED replications only show that the virtual hard disk is being used by another process.

I logged a ticket with Veeam, but they confirmed nothing more than it not being an issue with their software - they can see that post replication, the command is sent to merge the checkpoints.

I would really appreciate any ideas, help, suggestions.

Thank you.